# Sandboxed Solution - SPWeb Property Bag

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to create an SP2010 Sandboxed solution which involves a site collection administrator storing a piece of information in the Site collection root web property bag.

I can't think of a way I can do this as application pages aren't allowed and site pages cannot use code behind...

Is there another method that can be used to either

a) save data to spweb property bag or

b) store global data that can be used throughout the site?

Answer (score 8):

Create a plain ol Web Part that stores the info in the appropriate location (property bags, custom list etc).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can also [use SharePoint Designer](http://www.iwkid.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=42) to set property bag values.

1. Open a site
2. Click Site -> Site Settings
3. Click the Parameters tab

Comment: Yet another really useful feature in SPD. Pity it sucks for code editing.

Comment: And that's also a problem! Do not ever store sensitive information in the property bags. And if you use values from the property bags make sure that you have propertly error handling, since you never know what your users are up to...

Answer (score 0):

You should **use** SPWeb.GetProperty, SPWeb.SetProperty, SPWeb.AddProperty, **instead of** SPWeb.Properties.  SPWeb.Properties is **not supported** in sandbox.  Also, if you call SPWeb.Properties.Update(), it will fail, so do SPWeb.Update()